# How do I loop to prevent wrong user input?

Tags: python, loops, integer

> Hi all! My goal is to loop age so that male_cal or fem_cal (implicit) print correctly. Please help! Much thanks --> Pythonidaer <--

```
print("\nWelcome to the Daily Caloric Intake Calculator!")
```

## I don't know how to loop age like I did sex.

```
age = int(input("\nHow old are you in years? "))

sex = input("\nAre you a male or a female? Enter 'male' or 'female'. ").lower()
if sex == "female" or sex == "f":
    sex = "female"
elif sex == "male" or sex == "m":
    sex = "male"
else:
    sex = input("Sorry, there's only two choices: MALE or FEMALE. ").lower()
```

## The equation requires age be an integer. How can I foolproof?

```
height = float(input("\nHow tall are you in inches? "))
metric_height = float(height * 2.54)
weight = float(input("\nWhat is your weight in pounds? "))
metric_weight = int(weight * 0.453592)


activity_level = float(input("""
Please select your activity level:

Sedentary (enter '1.2')
Moderatively Active (enter '1.3')
Active? (enter '1.4')

"""))

male_cal = 10 * metric_weight + 6.25 * metric_height - 5 * age - 161
fem_cal = 10 * metric_weight + 6.25 * metric_height - 5 * age + 5

if (sex == "male"):

carbs = int(male_cal * .45)
protein = int(male_cal * .20)
fats = int(male_cal * .35)
print("\nYour DCI should be: ", int(male_cal), "calories a day.")
print(f"""\nThat means getting:
{carbs} cals from carbs, 
{fats} cals from fats, and 
{protein} cals from protein.""")
elif (sex == "female"):

carbs = int(fem_cal * .45)
protein = int(fem_cal * .20)
fats = int(fem_cal * .35)
print("\nYour DCI should be: ", int(fem_cal), "calories a day.")
print(f"""\nThat means getting:
{carbs} cals from carbs, 
{fats} cals from fats, and 
{protein} cals from protein.""")
```

Comment: There are several similar questions already, with complete answers.

Comment: use button `{}` to correctlu format code

Comment: Hi @TerryJanReedy I appreciate your feedback. Thanks to you as well furas. I am researching proper format for SO and Reddit, so that I can ask a question in the most concise way. I am also working on my research skills overall, so that I don't ask questions in the future that have already been answered. However, I will err on the side of getting my question answered if I am not sure. happy holidays :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input("\nHow old are you in years? "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('please put in a number')
```

This should do the Trick

Comment: You need wrap the code in a while loop to guarantee that age is set.

Comment: @Lyux thanks so much for the help! I tried this and it worked perfectly. However, I don't just want the answer, I want to understand what the code is doing so that I don't have to ask for the same technique in the future. My first SO post has made me very happy, but I have learned that before I ask again, I need to figure out how to ask the right questions so that I can first see if the question has already been answered. I also want to learn how to read python documentation, so that way I can read up on exceptions, Errors, breaks, loops, Cases, Classes, debugging, ETC. ... before asking again

Comment: So try to work out what the code is doing for yourself, which is in my opinion the best way to learn and understand and if you can't work it out ask a specific question on parts of the code and we'll gladly help you out.

Comment: In conjunction, this and Reddit also helped me figure out two other portions of the script. All major chunks of code I sought to fool-proof are done so. Next goal will be UX improvements, and eventually I will learn how to restructure the while loops into perhaps functions in a Class.